# Finding the DISK space for all the server instances

Tags: bash

In this bash script, the server list has all the list of serers for which the disk space should be calculated. They are ranging from c1 to c109. Now the servers from c100-c109 has a capacity below 50%, So i have to get the following message that says

"There is sufficient disk space available"

But, i am getting this message instead

"I seem to be running with an nonexistent amount of disk space"

Please if anybody can help me fixing this, it would be awesome. Let me know, if any clarifications you need. Here is the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# This script does a very simple test for checking disk space.
for VTIER in `cat serverlist`
do
space=$(ssh -q ${VTIER}@${VTIER} 'df -kh|grep ${ServerName}|cut -c 65-70')
echo "Checking disk space.... in ${VTIER}"
case $space in
[1-6]*)
Message="There is sufficient disk space available - $space full"
;;
[7-8]*)
Message="Keep an eye on the disk space - $space full."
;;
9[1-8])
Message="Better hurry with that new disk -  $space full."
;;
99)
Message="I'm drowning here! - $space full"
;;
*)
Message="I seem to be running with an nonexistent amount of disk space - $space full"
;;
esac
echo $Message
done
```

Comment: have you checked the value of `space` that's being evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

Your cut is incorrect:

```
marc@panic:/home/httpd/html$ df -kh|cut -c 65-70




marc@panic:/home/httpd/html$
```

Note the blank lines... that's not just whitespace. it's the cut output. Once you include the `k` option to force a block size, the block size column is removed, shortening each line, so you're actually cutting text from way past the end of each line. You might be better off using awk:

```
marc@panic:/home/httpd/html$ df -kh|awk '{print $5}'
Use%
7%
1%
1%
0%
1%
61%
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for nailing down to the awk command, it was so useful. but when i try to include it in my script. it is not working. Even i tried assigning awk to a variable..but its failing to execute.